# IQueryable vs IEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

Consider the following fragment:

```
IQueryable<Person> pQ = from p in db.People select p;
IEnumerable<Person> pE = pQ;

Console.WriteLine(pQ.Count());
Console.WriteLine(pE.Count());
```

Both give the same result, but if you track the generated SQL the `IQueryable` version issues a query using `COUNT`, whereas the `IEnumerable` version just issues a `SELECT`, pulling in all the rows and doing the count in memory, which is potentially very inefficient. The same applies for other methods such as `Sum()` and `Average()` and occurs in both EF6 and EF Core 3.

The reason is that `Count()` is an extension method and so binds to the static type of the variable (`IQueryable` in the first case, `IEnumerable` in the second) rather than the dynamic type (the same in both cases, since it's the same object).

This is a really nasty gotcha, meaning it's usually best to avoid `IEnumerable` in such cases. However, there is a workaround:

```
Console.WriteLine(pE.AsQueryable().Count());
```

which means the `SQL` `COUNT` is issued.

(Note: casting to `IQueryable` would work here too, but not in general - if the `IEnumerable` were purely referring to in-memory data then the cast would fail, but `AsQueryable()` would simply surround the object in a neutral wrapper.)

My question is this: Since this problem is so easy to overlook and can cause such inefficient behaviour, why is the call to `AsQueryable()` not simply embedded into the `IEnumerable` implementations of the extension methods?

Comment: The `IEnumerable` extension methods function differently from the `IQueryable` versions. This is not as evident with `Count`, but consider `Where`. In `IEnumerable`, this takes a predicate (boolean returning) lambda and uses it to filter the stream. In `IQueryable` this takes an `Expression` tree representing a lambda and converts it to SQL. By the time execution of the method occurs, the parameter is already the wrong type and can't be converted. In essence what your code does is convert `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` which is the same as calling `AsEnumerable` which executes the query.

Answer (score 0):

*My question is this: Since this problem is so easy to overlook and can cause such inefficient behavior, why is the call to `AsQueryable()` not simply embedded into the `IEnumerable` implementations of the extension methods?*

The reason is that not always you'd like to call `IQueryable` extension methods.

> If the type of source implements `IQueryable<T>`,
>   `AsQueryable<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement>)` returns it directly.
>   Otherwise, it returns an `IQueryable<T>` that executes queries by
>   calling the equivalent query operator methods in `Enumerable` instead of
>   those in `Queryable`.

In case you'd like to materialize query you may call `AsEnumerable` method which returns `IEnumerable<T>` or use assignment to `IEnumerable<T>` variable (as you did) and then calling `Count` method will again call `AsQueryable` method which will return original `IQueryable<T>` object and execute `Count` for `IQueryable<T>`.

The problem is that `IQueryable` uses `QueryProvider` that is translating given expression tree to actual query and not every expression tree is possible to translate to valid query which may result in error. There are many query providers that are/was not mature enough and it just threw exceptions in that case. Which I believe is even worse than performance degradation. Also Entity Framework Core team thinks that as some queries are partially translated and rest is evaluated locally(luckily EFCore doesn't throw exceptions).

If I may suggest you how to deal with this possible overlooking issue I would write roslyn analyzer that will investigate code and look for `IEnumerable<T> enumerable = queryable;` assignments and warn in case it found something. There might exist some already implemented on GitHub as you might not be the only one dealing with it.

Comment: I would disagree that throwing exceptions is worse than performance degradation. Exceptions tell you there's a problem and force you to address it. Poor performance slips by unnoticed.

Comment: The issue usually is in query provider implementation and another version may address it. In case exception is throw you'll address it and you'll never investigate if that was solved in future versions. And if you address it you will need for most of the queries go for materialization. So, I would still go for no exception translation.

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense. If you're calling an extension method on IEnumerable, then your bypassing the query provider almost entirely (aside from the basic SELECT), so you'll never be aware there was a bug in the provider in the first place, let alone that is was fixed.

Comment: One thing is a bug that should result in an exception. Other thing is query provider is not capable of translation(at some point in time/version) and that should not result in an exception. Makes sense?

Comment: No. Because the use of IEnumerable bypasses the query provider entirely. What's it is capable of is irrelevant.